# Trying to delete row, end up just removing user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to delete rows in an associated table from my User.

I have the ids I want to delete in integer, and I do:

```
<%= Follower.delete(delete_id) %>
```

what this ends up doing is just deleting the user_id column. However I'd like to delete the entire row. Which for some reason isn't working.

I also tried

```
<%= current_user.followers.delete(delete_id) %>
```

but that gives the same result. Anyone know why not the entire row ends up being deleted?

Comment: Follower.find(id).delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `delete` on the object you want to delete -- your code is calling `delete` on the `class`.

As @RailsOuter mentioned, a way to do this would be to to `Follower.find(delete_id).delete`; or if there are many with the same `delete_id` as their own `id`, you could do `Follower.where(id: delete_id).destroy_all`.